# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP not working properly

Tags: android, swipe, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I was Trying to implement onTouchListner for my custome listview for detecting swipe.
in this code both switch cases (`ACTION_DOWN` ,`ACTION_UP`) works , but when `ACTION_UP` triggers the values I got in the downx,downy becomes 0 .
and the code for detecting swipes is always saying swiped right(even when I just click!!)

```
            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
        {

            float downx = 0,downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0, movex = 0, movey = 0;
                switch(event.getAction())
                {


                    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    {
                        downx = event.getX();
                        downy = event.getY();
                        Log.i("TOUCH","DOWN");
                        break;

                    }                       

                    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                    {
                        upx = event.getX();
                        upy = event.getY();
                        Log.i("TOUCH","UP");
                        if(downx  < upx)
                        {
                            Log.w("TODO","Swiped right");

                        }
                        else if(upx < downx)
                        {
                            Log.w("TODO","Swiped left");
                        }

                        break;
                    }

            }

                Log.i("TOUCH_DOWN","x = "+downx+"y = "+ downy); 
                Log.i("TOUCH_MOVE","x = "+movex+"y = "+ movey); 
                Log.i("TOUCH_UP","x = "+upx+"y = "+ upy);   

            return true;
        }
    });



    return view;
}

}
```

Is there any way to make it work 
advises needed!!
thanks

Comment: declare downx,downy values globally..in your code they are re initialized to 0

Comment: oh man!! I didn't even think like that..Thank's .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   float downx = 0,downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0, movex = 0, movey = 0;
```

They get initialized everytime onTouch() is called.
Declare them globally as class members.

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)  {
       float downx = 0,downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0, movex = 0, movey = 0;
```

`onTouch` is called for each touch event, reinitializing all your local members. If you want to avoid this, keep it as class members,